# Estimating probability of superiority in an A/B test with multinomial outcomes

Tags: bayesian, ab-test, multiarmed-bandit

Let's say I have an A/B (/C etc.) test, where the outcome of each trial is draw from a multinomial distribution with unknown frequencies. Each possible outcome value $x_i$ has a specified utility, $w_i$. If I put an independent dirichlet prior $Dir(\alpha_0)$ on the outcome frequencies of each arm, how can I calculate (or approximate) the probability that each arm has the highest expected utility, after a given number of trials (without resorting to monte-carlo simulation)?

If there are only two outcomes 0 and 1, then the dirichlet reduces to a beta distribution and in the past I have used the integral $p^{best}_i = \int_0^1p_i(x)\Pi_{j \neq i}\mbox{cdf}_j(x) \mbox{dx}$, which can be estimated as the average over evenly spaced quantiles of $p_i$ of the product of the cdfs of the other arms, but this requires knowing the pdfs, cdfs, and inverse cdfs (to compute quantiles).

Perhaps normal approximation is the way to go?